# Getting CMake generated build to recognise my assembly macros

Tags: assembly, makefile, cmake, riscv

I am experimenting with CMake in my Risc-V assembly project (https://github.com/mcmenaminadrian/riscyforth/tree/cmake-experimental) - I have a CMakeLists.txt file like so:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18 FATAL_ERROR)

project(riscyforth LANGUAGES ASM)

add_executable(riscyforth 
    macros.S
    riscyforth.S
    basics.S
    core.S
    decision.S
    integer.S
    listwords.S
    loops.S
    outerloop.S
    search_create.S
    stackop.S
    transitions.S
    )

target_link_libraries(riscyforth
    libc
    )
```

This generates a Makefile but the build fails because the macros defined in macros.S are not recognised and are treated as unrecognised opcodes eg:

```
[  7%] Building ASM object CMakeFiles/riscyforth.dir/macros.S.o
[ 15%] Building ASM object CMakeFiles/riscyforth.dir/basics.S.o
/root/repos/riscyforth/basics.S: Assembler messages:
/root/repos/riscyforth/basics.S:7: Error: unrecognized opcode `codeend TYPEPROMPT,0x01'
/root/repos/riscyforth/basics.S:8: Error: unrecognized opcode `writecr'
/root/repos/riscyforth/basics.S:9: Error: unrecognized opcode `writechar 0x0A'
/root/repos/riscyforth/basics.S:10: Error: unrecognized opcode `writechar 0x3E'
/root/repos/riscyforth/basics.S:13: Error: unrecognized opcode `codeheader GETNEXTLINE_IMM,TYPEPROMPT,0x0'
```

(I thought this might have been related to the order in which files were added in add_executable so but macros.S first but that made no difference.)

How do I fix this?

Comment: Every source file should include **macro** definitions which it uses. In you case `basics.S` should include `macros.S`.

Comment: Nothing to do with Makefiles, as Tsyvarev says this appears is a problem with each file building individually.  CMake doesn't combine your asm sources into one, it just runs an assembler on them each separately, just like how `make` / `cmake` normally work for separate source files.

Comment: I don’t have this issue with the small hand written makefile though